# Parallel first order reaction

Tags: kinetics

[image]

I am not able to solve this question. Here's my working

[image: http://imgur.com/a/wcoI0u2]

Have I done this in the right way? Because my textbook gives answer as 4 moles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, there are two reactions for the 2 moles of A

$$\ce{A ->[rate\space =\space k_1] 2B}$$

$$\ce{A ->[rate\space =\space k_2] 2C}$$

$$\dfrac{k_1}{k_2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

The question asks for the total number of moles of A+B+C when the reaction is 75% complete.

- At that point 25% of A remains or 0.5 moles of A
- It does matter what the ratio of B and C produced is since either reaction of A creates 2 moles of product.  So there is 2*1.5 = 3 moles of product (B+C).

Thus there is 0.5 + 3 = 3.5 moles of A+B+C in the solution when the reaction is 75% complete.

There are 4 moles when the reaction is 100% complete.

*So the book answer is wrong.*

Comment: I don't understand how either reaction produces 2 moles  of product ......how did you conclude this.Is my solution wrong because I am getting different concentrations of C and B

Comment: @GENESECT - It is just the stoichiometry of the reaction. 1 molecule of A makes either 2 molecules of B or 2 molecules of C. So 1 mole of A produces 2 moles of B+C.

Comment: So some part of A makes B and remaining part makes C .The sum of which is 2

Comment: But what have I done wrong in my solution.......I am also getting same answer but it's wrong as It seems from your comments

Comment: Yes. I could figure out how much of B and how much of C, but that is extra work and I am lazy. // Really -- the less stuff you calculate the less you're likely to do wrong. So solve the problem the simplest way possible.

Comment: @GENESECT - The way that you calculated isn't *wrong*, you just did extra work.

Comment: @MaxW Btw, the answer given in the book is 3.5 only. OP didn't check it correctly